# Basement wiring with wood foundation

Tags: wiring, basement

I am in the process of finishing my basement. My house has a wood foundation and I am about to start wiring the lights and recepticals.

I am wondering, since the studs are the foundation of the house, am I allowed to drill thru the studs for electrical wiring? Or do I have to drill thru the top plates?

Answer (score 1):

A few screws or nails do nothing to the structural integrity of your studs.
A few holes for the wires are fine as long you don't make a swiss cheese out of them.

Comment: For most walls I agree, including load bearing ones. I wanted to make sure that it is ok for foundation studs. Do you know of any references that mention this?

Comment: No, but I seen it done many times and I did it.